# How to properly update values in a sql Database with Appcelerator?

Tags: database, sqlite, appcelerator

I am using sql adapter to work with a database. What is the proper way to handle updates?

The code below adds 1 point correctly to the sum_points field in the database of the entry with questionid 1624 , but there is also an error message (rs.fieldCount) coming up and console.log at the end is not executed

```
var fetchedTranslations = $.translationData;
fetchedTranslations.fetch({
query: { statement: 'UPDATE "translationsCollection" SET "sum_points" = "sum_points" + ? WHERE "questionid" = ?', params: [1,1624] } //correctly changes the value but results in error message (rs.fieldCount)
});
console.log("fetchedTranslations: " + JSON.stringify(fetchedTranslations));
}
```

views.xml:

```
 <Alloy>
<!--<Model src="translationsCollection"/>-->
<Collection src="translationsCollection" instance="true" id="translationData"/>
<Window id="learnQuestions" title="Learn">
<View id="learnQuestionContainer" layout="vertical" width="98%" borderWidth="2" borderRadius="5" backgroundColor="Alloy.CFG.design.backgroundColor" borderColor="#E6000000" height="98%">
    <View id="ratingBar" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" backgroundColor="orange" left="1%" width="98%">
        <Label id="pointsCounter" width="30%" left="30%" height="Ti.UI.SIZE"  top="0" text="pointsCounter" onClick="calculatePoints" top="0"/> 
        <!-- calculatePoints triggers the points update function-->
    </View>
    <ScrollView id="learnQuestionsContainer" layout="vertical" height="Ti.UI.SIZE" dataCollection="$.translationData" dataTransform="transformFunction">
    </ScrollView>
</View>
</Window>
```

trasnlationCollection.js (in models folder)

```
exports.definition = {
config: {
    columns: {
        "questionid": "real",
        "question": "text",
        "answer": "text",
        "difficulty": "real",
        "language": "text",
        "sum_points": "real",
        "sum_words": "real"
    },
    adapter: {
        type: "sql",
        collection_name: "translationsCollection",
        idAttribute : "questionid"
    }
},
extendModel: function(Model) {
    _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        idAttribute : "questionid",
        // extended functions and properties go here
    });
    return Model;
},
```

Labels in the Scrollview (that are populated by the database) are created programmatically.

**SOLUTION**

Added the model src in the .xml file and fetch and set the values as Rene suggested:

```
<Model src="translationsCollection"/> 

var fetchedTranslations = $.translationData;
var model = fetchedTranslations.get('1624');
console.log("model fetched: " + JSON.stringify(model));
model.set({sum_points: model.get('sum_points') + 1});
model.save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using collections and models, and not just a database. For most important things you don't need to use queries at all. Just look at the related [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Collection_and_Model_Objects) regarding models.

In your case, just get the model with a proper ID (or any backbone method to get them)

```
var model = $.fetchedTranslations.get('123');
model.set({sum_points: model.get('sum_points') + 1});
model.save();
```

Since collections are backbone based, I recommend checking the [backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/) too, so you can see how you can get by any other properties besides ID, filter, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When I try this code (and $.translationData.get('1624') where 1624 is the questionid console.log outputs as model undefined. questionid is set as idAttribute in the adapter and model (in the model.js) files.

Comment: how did you define the collection? You're referring to it with `$.` but usually that is instance collections, not global ones.

Comment: Ive added the collection src. I spent quite some time on the official docs on models and collections. unfortunately, im having a difficult time grasping how it works together. much more useful are docs like those : https://medium.com/all-titanium/enhancing-titanium-how-to-set-up-collections-with-databinding-39573cd30911 ;)

Comment: good to see my docs are being read. You will need to change the reference to your collection using just the name of the collection instead of the ID

Comment: Thanks. Ive added the solution based on your suggestion. I also did not add the Model src before to the collection.